# navigate from current directory

Tags: python-3.x

I have a script that I will host in a server, the program needs some variables and function from a file in 
a folder, how can I import the variables?

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\admin\Python\main (directorie of the main file)
```

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\admin\Python\main\variables
```

is there any way of navigating from the current directorie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin module `os` is what you are looking for:

````py
import os
ROOT_FOLDER = os.path.abspath('.') + '/'
print(ROOT_FOLDER)
os.chdir('/home/user/folder')```
````